# Using xlUp and getting odd results

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a column with numbers in it, starting at row 25. I want to fill an array with the row numbers for which this column has data. The following code works provided the numbers are arranged in rows that are far apart. I have assumed no more than twenty such rows exist within a 500 row range for simplicity. When rows are consecutively filled with data I get strange results. For example: on rows 45, 46, 47 there is data and yet this code returns only rows 45 and 47. I am new to VBA and am easily disheartened. Please help :)

```
Dim li_lastrow, li_current_row, rowvalue As Integer
Dim lb_finished As Boolean
Dim a(1 To 20) As Integer

i = 1

li_last_row = 500
lb_finished = False

Do Until lb_finished Or (i = 20)
    rowvalue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & li_last_row).End(xlUp).Row
If rowvalue <= 25 Then
    lb_finished = True
Else

    a(i) = rowvalue
    MsgBox a(i)

     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & li_last_row).Value = ""
    li_last_row = rowvalue
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Loop

Answer (score 1):

Up goes to the next cell where it changes between a empty and not empty cell. It behaves like Ctrl+Up.

```
'Only the last is a integer the first two are variants
'Dim li_lastrow, li_current_row, rowvalue As Integer
'Is equal to:
'Dim li_lastrow
'Dim li_current_row
'Dim rowvalue As Integer
Dim a(1 To 20) As Integer

i = 1

Dim currentRow as Integer
For currentRow = 500 to 26 Step -1
    'If the row is empty go to the next nonempty row
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentRow ,"C").Value = "" then
        currentRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentRow ,"C").End(xlUp).Row
    end if

    a(i) = currentRow
    MsgBox a(i)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentRow ,"C").Value = ""
    'Exit the for loop if we have 20 rows
    if i = 20 then
        exit for
    end if
    i = i + 1
Next
```